# How to invoke multiple web service using WSO2 ESB Proxy Service?

Tags: wso2, wso2-esb

I am new to wso2

I have a doubt,how to invoke two different web service using a proxy service. Is it is possible ??

Please help me on this

I have two different jar service,i need to call those using a proxy service based on condition

Is it possible to implement this?

Can anyone help me how to do this

Comment: When configuring the proxy, you can have multiple callout tasks.

Comment: Thanks for the reply Josh.. Can you elaborate more on this,i didn't get a clear picture

Comment: Do you have any examples on how to do this...

I have created two simple jar services and deployed into wso2

I want to create a proxy service for calling these two services based on any condition

For doing what are the steps i have to do,sorry since i am new to wso2 i didn't get a clear idea

Comment: https://docs.wso2.org/display/ESB480/Callout+Mediator

Comment: http://sparkletechthoughts.blogspot.com/2013/10/how-to-call-multiple-soap-operations.html?m=1

Comment: Thanks for the reply Josh... Actually i want to call two different service (different URL) using a Proxy service based on any condition. The above example is about to call different methods in s service using box carring session

Can you help me to do this please... Since i am new to wso2,i didn't    get a clear idea on how to do this

Comment: I have two different service 
1) One service to add and subtract two numbers
2) Another service to multiply and divide two numbers

I want to create a proxy service to call this two service based on any condition,say if 1st number greater than second number,i need to call 1st service,otherwise i need to call second service

How to implement this using a proxy service??